# Headings at the top and tables aligned vertically top

Tags: tables, align

I am new to LaTex and struggling to get some simple things work. The following code has two bugs for me:

1. generates headings to the left of table
2. tables of different sizes do not align vertically

Could someone help fix the above two problems please?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=0.75in,right=0.75in,top=.5in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \resizebox{\columnwidth}{!} {%
        \begin{tabular}{lll}

            Heading 1
            \begin{tabular}{ @{}l l@{} l@{} }
                \textbf{\scalebox{.7}[1.0]{\enspace asd}} \quad&    \textbf{\scalebox{.7}[1.0]{\enspace LMN\quad}} &   \textbf{\scalebox{.7}[1.0]{\enspace xyz \quad}} \\\hline  
                \enspace \tt{MYSTRING} \quad & \quad {A} & \quad {A} \\   
                \enspace \tt{MYSTRING} & \quad {B} & \quad {B} \\  
                \enspace \tt{MYSTRING} & \quad {J} & \quad {J} \\  
                \enspace \tt{MYSTRING} & \quad {K} & \quad {K} \\
                \hline
                \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Message 1}} & \textbf{Messsage 2} \\
            \end{tabular}   

            &

            Heading 2
            \begin{tabular}{ @{}l l@{} l@{} }
                \textbf{\scalebox{.7}[1.0]{\enspace asd}} \quad&    \textbf{\scalebox{.7}[1.0]{\enspace LMN\quad}} &   \textbf{\scalebox{.7}[1.0]{\enspace xyz \quad}} \\\hline  
                \enspace \tt{MYSTRING} \quad & \quad {A} & \quad {A} \\   
                \enspace \tt{MYSTRING} & \quad {B} & \quad {B} \\  
                \enspace \tt{MYSTRING} & \quad {C} & \quad {C} \\  
                \enspace \tt{MYSTRING} & \quad {D} & \quad {D} \\   
                \enspace \tt{MYSTRING} & \quad {E} & \quad {E} \\  
                \enspace \tt{MYSTRING} & \quad {F} & \quad {F} \\  
                \enspace \tt{MYSTRING} & \quad {G} & \quad {G} \\  
                \enspace \tt{MYSTRING} & \quad {H} & \quad {H} \\   
                \enspace \tt{MYSTRING} & \quad {I} & \quad {I} \\  
                \enspace \tt{MYSTRING} & \quad {J} & \quad {J} \\  
                \enspace \tt{MYSTRING} & \quad {K} & \quad {K} \\
                \hline
                \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Message 1}} & \textbf{Messsage 2} \\
            \end{tabular}   

            &

            Heading 3
            \begin{tabular}{ @{}l l@{} l@{} }
                \textbf{\scalebox{.7}[1.0]{\enspace asd}} \quad&    \textbf{\scalebox{.7}[1.0]{\enspace LMN\quad}} &   \textbf{\scalebox{.7}[1.0]{\enspace xyz \quad}} \\\hline  
                \enspace \tt{MYSTRING} \quad & \quad {A} & \quad {A} \\   
                \enspace \tt{MYSTRING} & \quad {B} & \quad {B} \\  
                \hline
                \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Message 1}} & \textbf{Messsage 2} \\
            \end{tabular}   


        \end{tabular}%
    }
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some suggestions and comments:

- There's no need for nested `tabular` environments in the `table` environment. A single level of `tabular`s should do. Use the `[t]` location specifier to inform LaTeX that they should be top-aligned with regard to each other. Use `\hspace{\fill}` instructions to maximize the amount of vertical whitespace between the tabulars.
- Place the header lines *inside* the respective `tabular` environments, and center them across the three columns via `\multicolumn{3}{c}{...}` wrappers.
- As far as I can tell, there's no need for the outer `\resizebox` directive or any of the `\scalebox` directives. I further recommend you get rid of all 26 [!] instances of `\enspace` and all 46 [!!] instances of `\quad`. If these directives are there as an attempt to change the amount of intercolumn whitespace, do learn how to modify the parameter `\tabcolsep`.
- To further reduce code clutter, get rid of all pairs of curly braces that surround the letters `A`, `B`, etc.
- Since most of the contents of the first column of each `tabular` environment need to be typeset using a monospaced font, just inform LaTeX about this fact by defining the respective column type as `>{\ttfamily}l` instead of just `l`.

[image]

---

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage[hmargin=0.75in,top=.5in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{} >{\ttfamily}lll @{}}
\multicolumn{3}{c}{Heading 1}\\[2ex]
\multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{asd} & LMN & xyz \\
\hline  
MYSTRING & A & A \\   
MYSTRING & B & B \\  
MYSTRING & J & J \\  
MYSTRING & K & K \\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{\textbf{Message 1}} & \textbf{Messsage 2} \\
\end{tabular}   
\hspace{\fill}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{} >{\ttfamily}lll @{}}
\multicolumn{3}{c}{Heading 2} \\[2ex]
\multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{asd} & LMN & xyz \\
\hline  
MYSTRING & A & A \\   
MYSTRING & B & B \\  
MYSTRING & C & C \\  
MYSTRING & D & D \\   
MYSTRING & E & E \\  
MYSTRING & F & F \\  
MYSTRING & G & G \\  
MYSTRING & H & H \\   
MYSTRING & I & I \\  
MYSTRING & J & J \\  
MYSTRING & K & K \\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{\textbf{Message 1}} & \textbf{Messsage 2} \\
\end{tabular}   
\hspace{\fill}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{} >{\ttfamily}lll @{}}
\multicolumn{3}{c}{Heading 3} \\[2ex]
\multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{asd} & LMN & xyz \\\hline  
MYSTRING & A & A \\   
MYSTRING & B & B \\  
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{\textbf{Message 1}} & \textbf{Messsage 2} \\
\end{tabular}   
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @Mico. Removing `monospace` part was very useful in its own right. The heading was like title, without number as in caption. I just found that I could use `\caption*`, which I prefer for automation purpose.

Comment: @xinit - Glad you found my answer useful. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you want exactly, especially for the column heads and all those `\resizebox`es, but here is a proposition, with the `subcaption` and `booktabs` packages. I'm sure it can be improved further.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=0.75in,right=0.75in,top=.5in,bottom=1in, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{float, caption, subcaption, booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
 \centering\small
\begin{subtable}[t]{0.32\linewidth}
\centering
 \caption{Heading 1}
 \begin{tabular}[t]{ @{}l l@{} l@{} }
 \textbf{\scalebox{.7}[1.0]{\enspace asd}} \quad& \textbf{\scalebox{.7}[1.0]{\enspace LMN\quad}} & \textbf{\scalebox{.7}[1.0]{\enspace xyz \quad}} \\\toprule
 \enspace \tt{MYSTRING} \quad & \quad {A} & \quad {A} \\
 \enspace \tt{MYSTRING} & \quad {B} & \quad {B} \\
 \enspace \tt{MYSTRING} & \quad {J} & \quad {J} \\
 \enspace \tt{MYSTRING} & \quad {K} & \quad {K} \\
 \bottomrule
                \addlinespace
 \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Message 1}} & \textbf{Message 2} \\
 \end{tabular}
\end{subtable}
\hfill
\begin{subtable}[t]{0.32\linewidth}
\centering
\caption{Heading 2}
            \begin{tabular}{ @{}l l@{} l@{} }
                \textbf{\scalebox{.7}[1.0]{\enspace asd}} \quad& \textbf{\scalebox{.7}[1.0]{\enspace LMN\quad}} & \textbf{\scalebox{.7}[1.0]{\enspace xyz \quad}} \\\toprule
                \enspace \tt{MYSTRING} \quad & \quad {A} & \quad {A} \\
                \enspace \tt{MYSTRING} & \quad {B} & \quad {B} \\
                \enspace \tt{MYSTRING} & \quad {C} & \quad {C} \\
                \enspace \tt{MYSTRING} & \quad {D} & \quad {D} \\
                \enspace \tt{MYSTRING} & \quad {E} & \quad {E} \\
                \enspace \tt{MYSTRING} & \quad {F} & \quad {F} \\
                \enspace \tt{MYSTRING} & \quad {G} & \quad {G} \\
                \enspace \tt{MYSTRING} & \quad {H} & \quad {H} \\
                \enspace \tt{MYSTRING} & \quad {I} & \quad {I} \\
                \enspace \tt{MYSTRING} & \quad {J} & \quad {J} \\
                \enspace \tt{MYSTRING} & \quad {K} & \quad {K} \\
                \bottomrule
                \addlinespace
                \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Message 1}} & \textbf{Message 2} \\
            \end{tabular}
\end{subtable}
\hfill
\begin{subtable}[t]{0.32\linewidth}
\centering
            \caption{Heading 3}
            \begin{tabular}{ @{}l l@{} l@{} }
                \textbf{\scalebox{.7}[1.0]{\enspace asd}} \quad& \textbf{\scalebox{.7}[1.0]{\enspace LMN\quad}} & \textbf{\scalebox{.7}[1.0]{\enspace xyz \quad}} \\\toprule
                \enspace \tt{MYSTRING} \quad & \quad {A} & \quad {A} \\
                \enspace \tt{MYSTRING} & \quad {B} & \quad {B} \\
                \bottomrule
                \addlinespace
                \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Message 1}} & \textbf{Message 2} \\
            \end{tabular}
\end{subtable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a tabular environment to list the tables next to each other it is often better to use minipages, especially within a `table` environment. That also makes it easier to align the tables. Apart from that I think you have a couple of things that are not necessary. For example you remove the spaces between columns with `@{}` and then add new spaces with `\enspace` and `\quad`. And you sould avoid `\tt` and use `\texttt` instead. I have rewritten the tables in the way closer to how I would present them below.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=0.75in,right=0.75in,top=.5in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
  \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
    \mbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\linewidth}
        \caption{Heading 1}
        \begin{tabular}[t]{lll}
          \textbf{asd} & \textbf{LMN} & \textbf{xyz} \\ \hline  
          \texttt{MYSTRING} & A & A \\   
          \texttt{MYSTRING} & B & B \\  
          \texttt{MYSTRING} & J & J \\  
          \texttt{MYSTRING} & K & K \\ \hline
          \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Message 1}} & \textbf{Messsage 2}
        \end{tabular}             
      \end{minipage}}%
    \mbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\linewidth}
        \caption{Heading 2}
        \begin{tabular}{lll}
          \textbf{asd} & \textbf{LMN} & \textbf{xyz} \\\hline  
          \texttt{MYSTRING} & A & A \\   
          \texttt{MYSTRING} & B & B \\  
          \texttt{MYSTRING} & C & C \\  
          \texttt{MYSTRING} & D & D \\   
          \texttt{MYSTRING} & E & E \\  
          \texttt{MYSTRING} & F & F \\  
          \texttt{MYSTRING} & G & G \\  
          \texttt{MYSTRING} & H & H \\   
          \texttt{MYSTRING} & I & I \\  
          \texttt{MYSTRING} & J & J \\  
          \texttt{MYSTRING} & K & K \\ \hline
          \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Message 1}} & \textbf{Messsage 2}
        \end{tabular}   
      \end{minipage}}%
    \mbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\linewidth}
        \caption{Heading 3}
        \begin{tabular}{lll}
          \textbf{asd} & \textbf{LMN} & \textbf{xyz} \\ \hline  
          \texttt{MYSTRING} & A & A \\   
          \texttt{MYSTRING} & B & B \\ \hline
          \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Message 1}} & \textbf{Messsage 2} \\
        \end{tabular}         
      \end{minipage}}
  }
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

And more solution ...

[image]

in mWE is used `makecell` package for column heads and `tabularx` for enclosed (sub)tables and `\caption{...}` for tables captions:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,
            left=0.75in,right=0.75in,top=.5in,bottom=1in, 
            showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{titlesec}
%\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
    \newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
    \renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries\normalfont}
\usepackage{caption, subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
    \small
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} CCC @{}}
    \caption{Heading 1}
    \begin{tabular}[t]{ @{}>{\ttfamily}l c c@{} }
\thead{asd} & \thead{LMN} & \thead{xyz} \\
    \toprule
MYSTRING    &   A   &   A               \\
MYSTRING    &   B   &   B               \\
MYSTRING    &   J   &   J               \\
MYSTRING    &   K   &   K               \\
    \bottomrule
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Message 1}} & \textbf{Message 2}    \\
    \end{tabular}
    &   \caption{Heading 2}
        \begin{tabular}{ @{}>{\ttfamily}l c c@{} }
        \thead{asd} & \thead{LMN} & \thead{xyz} \\
        \toprule
        MYSTRING    &   B   &   B               \\
        MYSTRING    &   C   &   C               \\
        MYSTRING    &   D   &   D               \\
        MYSTRING    &   E   &   E               \\
        MYSTRING    &   F   &   F               \\
        MYSTRING    &   G   &   G               \\
        MYSTRING    &   H   &   H               \\
        MYSTRING    &   I   &   I               \\
        MYSTRING    &   J   &   J               \\
        MYSTRING    &   K   &   K               \\
    \bottomrule
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Message 1}} & \textbf{Message 2}    \\
    \end{tabular}
        &   \caption{Heading 3}
            \begin{tabular}{ @{}>{\ttfamily}l c c@{} }
            \thead{asd} & \thead{LMN} & \thead{xyz} \\
            \toprule
            MYSTRING    &   A   &   A               \\
            MYSTRING    &   B   &   B               \\
        \bottomrule
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Message 1}} & \textbf{Message 2}    \\
            \end{tabular}
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```